# Nuxt Generate Freezes

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've been struggling with a Nuxt Generate problem for quite some while. Whenever I add **ssr: true** to nuxt.config and try to generate dynamic routes, the generation freezes. Nuxt generates x amount of routes just how I want them, but is unable to finish the process. No error is given by Nuxt, just stops at some route. My generate setup is as simple as this:

```
  generate: {
    crawler: false,
    interval: 150,
    routes () {
      return axios.get(process.env.API_URL + '/events/routes').then(res => {
        /* 
           API returns an array of event routes:
          ['/organiser/event', '/organiser/event-1']
        */

        return res.data
      })
    }
  }
```

It seems to work as expected when I manually add an array of routes, as follows:

```
routes: ['/organiser/event, '/organiser/event-1', '/etc/event']
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The default value of the `ssr` property is `true` and thus you can omit `ssr: true` from `nuxt.config.js`. And in your case you should omit it because it's causing you issues.